# Can't use terminal any more after editing bashrc file

Tags: command-line, bashrc

Last time when I added `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk" (java path could be different)
source /etc/environment (and this too )` at the end of bashrc file. when i saved and exited, Terminal keeps asking for password all the time , though I am putting correct password .. Is there a way to open bashrc file and remove `source /.../` ??

Comment: @Serg you are right. I did that. Can you please convert your comment as Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using GUI, you can open the file with `gedit` text editor and correct whatever issues you may have with `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Alternatively, one could spawn `dash` , Debian Amquist Shell, which is default scripting shell for Ubuntu. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  and run `gnome-terminal -e dash`. This will launch `gnome-terminal` with `dash`, and then you can access and edit your file with `nano $HOME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

**I can't use command line what do I do? use GUI i.e. Nautilus (file manager)**

Now go to `/etc` directory in root, and look for `skel` directory, now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden files, now right click to copy `.bashrc` file in it.

Now go to your home directory, rename your old messed up `.bashrc` file, right click rename it to `.bashrc_backup` or anything your like. Now right click paste the new `.bashrc` file. **Done!**

**Additionally:** you can open old `.bashrc` file ( now `.bashrc_backup`) and copy your old aliases or modified `$PATH` if any and paste then at the end of new `.bashrc` file. In this case you can use Gedit (text editor) to edit them (In this case I believe `$PATH` and aliases are fine, if not ignore them)

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your bashrc

Backup:

```
 cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
```

Copy .bashrc file over yours:

```
  cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Load the new one:

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Yes . . . but if `.bashrc` is messed up, how does one get to the terminal to execute all these commands in the first place ?

Comment: you can use nautilus (file manager) to copy and rename files

Comment: @edwardtorvalds  That's the better approach. The `cp` command is basically inaccessible for user, but file manager tools are accessible. That's exactly what GAD3R should have posted